# Си.Нисходящая сортировка слиянием. Метод слияния абстрактный обменный

Tags: c, сортировка, сортировка-слиянием

В чем ошибка?Не могу разобраться...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


void merge( int *a, int lb, int split, int ub, int* count) {

  int pos1=0;
  int pos2=ub-lb;
  int pos3=lb;
  int *temp = (int*)malloc((ub+1) * sizeof(int)); 
  int m , b,f;
  for(m = 0; m<split ;m++){
    temp[m]=a[m];
  }
  for(b = split,f = ub; b<ub ;b++ ,f--){
    
    temp[b]=a[f];
  }

  while (pos1 <= pos2 ) {
    if (temp[pos1] > temp[pos2]){
      a[pos3] = temp[pos2--];
      (*count)++;
    }
    else{
      a[pos3] = temp[pos1++];
      (*count)++;
    }
    pos3++;
  }
}

void mergeSort(int *a, int lb, int ub, int* count) {
  long split;

  if (lb < ub) {
    split = (lb + ub)/2;

    mergeSort(a, lb, split, count);
    mergeSort(a, split+1, ub, count);
    merge(a, lb, split, ub, count);
  }
}

void arrprint(int *arr, int n) {
    printf("%d", *arr);
    int i;
    for ( i = 1; i < n; i++) printf(" %d", arr[i]);
    puts("");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int n = 10;
    int *arr = NULL; 
    arr = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof *arr); 
    int c = 0; 
    int* count = &c; 
    srand(time(NULL));
    int s;
    for ( s = 0; s < n; s++ )
        arr[s] = rand() % 50;

    arrprint(arr, n);
    mergeSort(arr, 0, n-1, count);
    arrprint(arr, n);

    free(arr);
    puts("");

    printf("Comparison count: %d\n", *count);

    return 0;
}
```

**UPD** теперь фиксированные значения..я что-то неправильно считаю ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
void mergeAbstract(int* a,int lb,int split,int ub,int* count, int* swaps)
{
    int size = ub - lb + 1;
    int *sub = (int*)malloc((ub+1) * sizeof(int)); 
    int i = 0, j = size - 1, k = lb;
    int s;
    for( s = 0; s < split+1-lb; s++) sub[s] = a[lb + s];
    for(s = split+1-lb; s < size; s++) sub[s] = a[ub - (s - (split+1-lb))];

    while(i <= j)
    {
        (*count) += 2;
        if(sub[i] > sub[j])
        {
            (*swaps)++;
            a[k] = sub[j];
            j--;
        }
        else 
        {
            (*swaps)++;
            a[k] = sub[i];
            i++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    (*count)++;
free(sub);
}



void mergeSort(int *a, int lb, int ub, int* count,int* swaps) {
  long split;

  if (lb < ub) {
    split = (lb + ub)/2;

    mergeSort(a, lb, split, count, swaps);
    mergeSort(a, split+1, ub, count,swaps);
    mergeAbstract(a, lb, split, ub, count,swaps);
  }
}

void arrprint(int *arr, int n) {
    printf("%d", *arr);
    int i;
    for ( i = 1; i < n; i++) printf(" %d", arr[i]);
    puts("");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int n = 10;
    int *arr = NULL; 
    arr = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof *arr); 
    int c = 0; 
    int* count = &c; 
    int h = 0; 
    int* swaps = &h; 
    srand(time(NULL));
    int s;
    for ( s = 0; s < n; s++ )
        arr[s] = rand() % 50;

    arrprint(arr, n);
    mergeSort(arr, 0, n-1, count, swaps);
    arrprint(arr, n);

    free(arr);
    puts("");

    printf("Comparison ans swaps : %d %d\n", *count ,*swaps);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: пока стрельнуло : `merge(a, lb, split, ub, count);` => может быть `merge(a, lb,` **split+1** `, ub, count);` ?

Comment: @AlexGlebe всё равно что попало выводит.Сейчас обновлю ответ.

Comment: @AlexGlebe всё таки что и где считать? :(

Comment: Скажите точно : ошибка чего ? Сортировки ?

Comment: @AlexGlebe  да сортирует то вроде как верно.Только что-то не так считается видимо.